# Entity Framework 2.0: Cannot update EntityCollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say we have the "EntityCollection products".

Then the following doesn't work:

```
foreach (var product in products)
{
 product.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now();
}
```

As you can also not index an EntityCollection, how do you modify an entity in en EntityCollection?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "doesn't work?"

Comment: Well, when executing Visual Studio complains that "products" is an enumerable collection, which you can't change during enumeration. Then, when I use "for (int i = 0; i < products.count;i++){product[i].LastUpdate = DateTime.Now();}" , it complains that "products" is not indexable...

Comment: Can you show the code where products is declared / initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029493/update-existing-entities-collections-in-entity-with-linq-to-entities/4074331#4074331), i create a generic method to update EntityCollection. Giv me your feed back.

You juste have to modify your product in your products entity collections. And call my `GenericUpdateEntityCollection(YourEntityCollection, YourObjectContext);` and there you go

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
foreach (var product in products.ToArray())
{
     product.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now();
}
```

You have to copy elements for enumeration with `ToArray()`, so you can change `products`.