# Update existing EntityCollection in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4, edmx

I try to work with link to entity, and i want to work directly with my entity in my application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Calandar.Business.Manager.Data;

namespace Calandar.Business.Models.Args
{
    public class SaveExpertArgs
    {
        public ExpertEntity Expert { get; set; }
        public SaveExpertArgs(ExpertEntity expert)
        {
            Expert = expert;
        }
    }
}

public ExpertEntity SaveExpert(SaveExpertArgs args)
{            
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CalendarContainer"].ConnectionString;

    using (CalendarContainer dbContext = new CalendarContainer(connString))
    {             
        ExpertEntity expert = (from e in dbContext.ExpertEntities
                               where e.ExpertIdentifier == args.Expert.ExpertIdentifier
                               select e).FirstOrDefault();
        if (expert == null)
        {
            args.Expert.ExpertIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid();
            dbContext.AddToExpertEntities(args.Expert);
        }
        else
        {
            dbContext.ExpertEntities.ApplyCurrentValues(args.Expert);               

            foreach (TimeSlotEntity t in args.Expert.TimeSlotEntities)
            {
                dbContext.TimeSlotEntities.ApplyCurrentValues(t);
            }
        }              

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return args.Expert;
    }
}
```

I try to save my expert entity and it's working, but i dont know how to save my EntityCollection in my expert Entity. some body can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found how i could update my entity collection.

There is my technique. I did not find any documentation on the technique, so give me your feed back

```
public ExpertEntity SaveExpert(SaveExpertArgs args)
        {

            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CalendarContainer"].ConnectionString;
            using (CalendarContainer dbContext = new CalendarContainer(connString))
            {
                ExpertEntity expert = (from e in dbContext.ExpertEntities
                                       where e.ExpertIdentifier == args.Expert.ExpertIdentifier
                                       select e).FirstOrDefault();
                if (expert == null)
                {
                    args.Expert.ExpertIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid();
                    dbContext.AddToExpertEntities(args.Expert);
                }
                else
                {
                    dbContext.ExpertEntities.ApplyCurrentValues(args.Expert);
                    GenericUpdateEntityCollection(args.Expert.TimeSlotEntities, dbContext);
                }
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                return args.Expert;
            }
        } 


private void GenericUpdateEntityCollection<T>(EntityCollection<T> collection, ObjectContext dbContext)
            where T : EntityObject, new()
        {
            int count = collection.Count();
            int current = 0;
            List<T> collectionItemList = collection.ToList();
            bool isAdded = false;
            while (current < count)
            {
                Object obj = null;
                // Essai de récupéré l'objet dans le context pour le mettre à jour
                dbContext.TryGetObjectByKey(collectionItemList[current].EntityKey, out obj);
                if (obj == null)
                {
                    // Si l'objet n'existe pas, on en créer un nouveau
                    obj = new TimeSlotEntity();
                    // On lui donne l'entity Key du nouvelle objet
                    ((T)obj).EntityKey = collectionItemList[current].EntityKey;
                    // On l'ajoute au context, dans le timeslot
                    dbContext.AddObject(((T)obj).EntityKey.EntitySetName, obj);
                    // On récupère l'objet du context qui à le même entity key que le nouveau recu en pramètre, le but est d'avoir un context d'attacher
                    dbContext.TryGetObjectByKey(collectionItemList[current].EntityKey, out obj);
                    // On change l'état de l'objet dans le context pour modifier, car 
                    dbContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(obj, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
                    // On change l'état de l'objet passé en paramètre pour qu'il soit au même state que celui dans le context
                    collection.CreateSourceQuery().Context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(collectionItemList[current], System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
                    // On place notre flag pour dire que nous avons ajouter dans le context les donnée
                    isAdded = true;
                }

                if (obj != null)
                {
                    // On applique les changements de l'objet passé en parametre à celui dans le context
                    dbContext.ApplyCurrentValues<T>(((T)obj).EntityKey.EntitySetName,collectionItemList[current]);
                    // On replace les state des deux objet, celui dans le context et celui passé en parametre à added pour la sauvegarde.
                    if (isAdded)
                    {
                        dbContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(obj, System.Data.EntityState.Added);
                        collection.CreateSourceQuery().Context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(collectionItemList[current], System.Data.EntityState.Added);
                    }
                }
                current++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try get rid of the else:

```
public ExpertEntity SaveExpert(SaveExpertArgs args)
{            
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CalendarContainer"].ConnectionString;

    using (CalendarContainer dbContext = new CalendarContainer(connString))
    {             
        ExpertEntity expert = (from e in dbContext.ExpertEntities
                               where e.ExpertIdentifier == args.Expert.ExpertIdentifier
                               select e).FirstOrDefault();
        if (expert == null)
        {
            args.Expert.ExpertIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid();
            dbContext.AddToExpertEntities(args.Expert);
        }
        //else
        //{
            dbContext.ExpertEntities.ApplyCurrentValues(args.Expert);               

            foreach (TimeSlotEntity t in args.Expert.TimeSlotEntities)
            {
                dbContext.TimeSlotEntities.ApplyCurrentValues(t);
            }
        //}              

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return args.Expert;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working, i get error : The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Comment: You can try use the "Include" command on your initial load to bring though the child objects from the expert. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx

Comment: I try to do exper.TimeSlotEntities.Load(); But when i work with my arg.Expert.TimeSlotEntities, this object is deconnected. It's there a way to work with the WrappedRelatedEntities?